# Comparing character strings in separate cells in Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large Excel spreadsheet with alpha-numeric data. I want to be able to compare two cells in different row side by side and return the difference in another cell.

e.g. I have in cell B2, "tom, rick, mike, I" and in cell C2, "mike, rick". I need to 
compare the cell C2 to cell B2 and return the difference in cell D2 which in this case would be the characters " tom, I". They are separated with "," and they can be in different order as you can see in the example.

Comment: And what have you tried? If you haven't tried anything then you might want to use `SPLIT` or `REPLACE` and see how it works out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Split each string into a list of items.  Compare each item in the first list with the second list, adding those items that are not in the second list to a third.  You might need to expand it to work with your list which contains spaces and commas.

```
Public Function ListDiff(names1 As String, names2 As String) As String

    Dim list1() As String
    Dim list2() As String

    list1 = Split(names1, ",")
    list2 = Split(names2, ",")
    list3 = ""

    For i = LBound(list1) To UBound(list1)
        If Not existsInList(list2, list1(i)) Then
            list3 = list3 & "," & list1(i)
        End If
    Next i
    'remove leading comma
    ListDiff = Right(list3, Len(list3) - 1)

End Function

Public Function existsInList(list() As String, item As String) As Boolean

    exists = False
    i = LBound(list)
    bFound = False

    While i <= UBound(list) And Not bFound
        If list(i) = item Then
            bFound = True
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    existsInList = bFound

End Function
```